# VBA Outlines not pasted

Tags: vba, excel

I copy a set of data from one worksheet to another. However the outlines (small + signs which collapse certain rows) are not copied. Can you tell me why?

I use the following code:

```
Dim rangeToCopy As Range
Set rangeToCopy = sourceWorksheet.Range("A26:A100")

Dim insertIntoRow As String
insertIntoRow = "A1"
Dim rangeToPaste As Range
Set rangeToPaste = destWorksheet.Range(insertIntoRow)

rangeToCopy.Copy
rangeToPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Could you provide more details. Especially rangetopaste

Comment: You have to copy the entire rows to get the outlines.

Comment: how would it look like?

Comment: `Set rangeToCopy = sourceWorksheet.Range("26:100")` ?